# to print the number of times that the substring occurs in the given string from left to right in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

In this challenge, the user enters a string and a substring. User has to print the number of times that the substring occurs in the given string. String traversal will take place from left to right, not from right to left.

Example:

```
Input:  
WoW!ItSCoOWoWW
oW

Output:
2
```

Code:

```
def count_substring(string, sub_string):
    j=0
    flag=0
    counter=0
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if string[i] == sub_string[j]:
            if(j==0):
                flag=i
            j+=1
        else:
            j=0
            if(j==len(sub_string)-1):
                counter+=1
                i=flag+1
                j=0
    return counter

if __name__ == '__main__':
    string = input().strip()
    sub_string = input().strip()

    count = count_substring(string, sub_string)
    print(count)
```

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/shivangi/Documents/python codes/hackerrank solutions.py",
>   line 24, in 
>       count = count_substring(string, sub_string)   File "C:/Users/shivangi/Documents/python codes/hackerrank solutions.py",
>   line 7, in count_substring
>       if string[i] == sub_string[j]: IndexError: string index out of range

I do not understand why it is showing "string index out of range" and how can it be solved

Answer (score 6):

You can simply do next:

```
input_str = 'WoW!ItSCoOWoWW'
pattern = 'oW'
print(input_str.count(pattern)) # will output 2
```

And you don't need so complicated solution

Also same with using regexp:

```
import re
input_str = 'WoW!ItSCoOWoWW'
pattern = 'oW'
print(len(re.findall(pattern, input_str))) # also output 2
```

and simple for loop implementation

```
idx = 0
pattern = 'oW'
input_str = 'WoW!ItSCoOWoWW'
pattern_len = len(pattern)
counter = 0

for ch in input_str:
    if ch == pattern[idx]:
        idx += 1
    else:
        idx = 0

    if pattern_len == idx:
        counter += 1
        idx = 0

print(counter) # 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an index out of bounds because of `j`. So let's say the `string` is `WowWowWow` and the `sub_string` is `ow`. So when you are in the 4. loop, your `i = 3` so you already checked `Wow` and you found one instance of the `sub_string`. But in that case, your `j=2` because it got increased by one when you found the first `o` and then again when you found the first lower case `w`. But Your `sub_string` has no value at index `[2]`. So your `sub_string[j]` is then out of bounds. I hope everything is clear.

A better solution would be to use

```
counter = string.count(sub_string)
print(counter)
```

or

```
print(string.count(sub_string))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also split the string with the substring. It will return a list with  **n + 1** elements. For example, if substring occurs 2 times, then the length of list will be 3. So we need to reduce 1 from that list.

```py
s = 'WoW!ItSCoOWoWW'
count = len(s.split('oW')) - 1 # output 2
```

checked for this example, works fine. Not sure if it works for other example as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
#This will definitely work#
#Use find function to get lower index where sub_string found#
def count_substring(string, sub_string):
    counter=0
    for i in range(len(string)-len(sub_string)):
        pos=string.find(sub_string)
        if pos!=-1:
            pos+=1
            string=string[pos+1:]
            counter+=1
    return count
if __name__ == '__main__':
    string = input().strip()
    sub_string = input().strip()
    count = count_substring(string, sub_string)
    print(count)
```

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more what you did? Answers with just a bunch of code are not accepted well.

Answer (score 0):

While searching for substrings please make sure that it counts overlaps.

Eg- string: rabdadada substring: dada Count should come two not one

```
def countSubstr(string, sub_string):
    count = start = 0
    while True:
        start = string.find(sub_string, start) + 1
        if start > 0:
            count+=1
        else:
            return count

if __name__ == '__main__':
    string = input().strip()
    sub_string = input().strip()

    count = countSubstr(string, sub_string)
    print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_substring(string, sub_string):
    c = 0
    for i in range(len(string)):
       if string[i:].startswith(sub_string):
          c = c + 1
    return c

if __name__ == '__main__':
   string = input().strip()
   sub_string = input().strip()

   count = count_substring(string, sub_string)
   print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Code 1

```
def count_substring(string, sub_string):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if string[i:].startswith(sub_string):
            count += 1
    return count
if __name__ == '__main__':
    string = input().strip()
    sub_string = input().strip()

count = count_substring(string, sub_string)
print(count)
```

## Code 2

```
string, substring = (input().strip(), input().strip())
print(sum([ 1 for i in range(len(string)-len(substring)+1) if 
string[i:i+len(substring)] == substring]))
```

### Using List Comprehension

In a list comprehension, we slide through bigger string by one position at a time with the sliding window of length of smaller string. We can compute the sliding count by substracting the length of smaller string from bigger string. For each slide, we compare that part of bigger string with our smaller string and generate 1 in a list if match found. Sum of all of these 1's in a list will give us total number of matches found.

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_substring(string, sub_string):
    c = 0
    for i in range(0, len(string)):
        if string[i:i+len(sub_string)] == sub_string:
            c += 1
    return c


print(count_substring("In the convential world, it won't ever happen", 'lD,'))
```

Answer (score 0):

What's with all the unnecessary complications?  This code will work, and count any overlaps, as others have mentioned.  There's a simpler answer as well, but some people prefer using find().  It increments the counter if the result of find() is greater than -1 because that's what find() returns if there is no match.  If there is a match it tells you the position in the string, so as long is the result is anywhere between 0 and the end of the string it will increment the counter.  You could also cut down the amount of loops if you subtract the length of the substring from the for loop.  Shouldn't matter in most cases, but if your substring is really really long there's no reason to keep checking for it if you don't even have that many characters left in your main string.

```
def count_substring(string, sub_string):
    counter = 0
    for x in range(0, len(string)):
        if string.find(sub_string, x, x+len(sub_string)) > -1:
            counter += 1
    return counter

if __name__ == '__main__':
    string = input().strip()
    sub_string = input().strip()    
    count = count_substring(string, sub_string)
    print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by more than one way

```
def count_substring(string, sub_string):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(string)-len(sub_string)+1):
        if (string[i:i+len(sub_string)] == sub_string):
            count += 1
    return count


import re
def count_substring(string, sub_string):
    match = re.findall('(?='+sub_string+')',string)
    return len(match)


def count_substring(string, sub_string):
    sum_1 = 0
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if sub_string[0] == string[i]:
            sum_1 += string.count(sub_string,i,len(sub_string)+i)
    return sum_1
```

In the last solution I make this conditional statement inside the loop to avoid repeating the sequence more than once

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_substring(string, sub_string):
    stringLength = len(string)
    subStringLength = len(sub_string)
    times = stringLength -subStringLength
    i=0
    result =0
    while (i<=times):
        if string[i:subStringLength] == sub_string:
            result+=1
        subStringLength+=1
        i+=1
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_substring(string, sub_string):
        ans=0
        lenght=len(sub_string)
        for i in range(0, len(string)):
            if sub_string in string[i:lenght+i]:
                ans+=1
            else:
                pass
        return ans
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        string = input().strip()
        sub_string = input().strip()
        
        count = count_substring(string, sub_string)
        print(count)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
def count_substring(string, sub_string):
  j=0
  counter=0
  for i in range(len(string)):
    if string[i] == sub_string[j]:
      j+=1
    else:
      j = 0
    if j == len(sub_string):
      j = 0
      counter += 1
  return counter

if __name__ == '__main__':
  string = input().strip()
  sub_string = input().strip()

  count = count_substring(string, sub_string)
  print(count)
```

Comment: Your code does not work properly, try it with a string like `halloichallokalilla` and the sub_string `all`, your result would be 3, but it should be just 2... your code-logic is messed up

Answer (score -1):

```
def count_substring(string, sub_string):
    subIndex = 0
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if len(string) >= len(sub_string):
            if string.find(sub_string)>-1:
                count = i
                subIndex = string.index(sub_string)
            string = string[subIndex+i:]
    return count
```

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more what you did? Answers with just a bunch of code are not accepted well.

Comment: Function gets first sub in the string and takes index number of it, then starts search again form that index number to find sub again. And counts how many times find the sub in the string. I tried many different sub and string and it worked very well.

Comment: All right. Additionally, in line with how to answer in SO, it would be even better if you posted this in your answer + exemplified at least with the example provided by OP.

Comment: Also explain how your solution differs or complement already posted answers. This is a rather old question, after all, and answers are piling up. Providing some height of view would help.